Avoid unnecessary copy in ternary operator
My understanding in that the type that the ternary operator evaluates to in the following function is std::string, i.e. it's a value, not a reference.
Is there a trick to avoid copying the string when the first branch is evaluated?
bool f(const std::vector<std::string>& vec, const std::string& s) {
    const std::string& s2 = !s.empty() && s[0] == '{' ? s : '{' + s + '}';
    for (const std::string& v : vec) {
        if (v == s2)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

EDIT:
Looks like I formulated the question too specifically. I meant for the code with strings to just be an example. The question I had in mind is more general. If you need a potential expensive modification for a large object, but, if a condition is met, could use the object as is, is there a way to bind either the original object or the result of the computation to a reference, without copying the original object if the computation is not required?

I don't think there's a way to concatenate strings without copying.

@Barmar but there are ways to avoid copy-concatenating in the case where it is not required.

Now I understand the question.


Is there a trick to avoid copying the string when the first branch is evaluated?

Not with the tenary operator alone, no.  But you can break out the search loop separately so you can pass a search string by reference to it, and then use the operator to invoke the loop with the desired search string, eg:
bool f(const std::vector<std::string>& vec, const std::string& s) {

    auto findIt = [&vec](const std::string& s) {
        for (const std::string& v : vec) {
            if (v == s)
               return true;
        }
        return false;
        // or simply:
        // return std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), s) != vec.end();
    };

    return (!s.empty() && s[0] == '{')
        ? findIt(s)
        : findIt('{' + s + '}');
}


This may be better, because it doesn't even create the temporary on the stack if it's not needed.

You could flip the algorithm inside out. Bonus points you get to reuse standard algorithms:
bool f(std::vector<std::string> const& haystack, std::string const& needle) {
    using std::ranges::any_of;

    if (needle.starts_with('{'))
        return any_of(haystack, [&](std::string const& v) { return v == needle; });

    return any_of(haystack, [&](std::string_view v) { //
        return v.length() == needle.length() + 2      //
            && v.starts_with('{')                     //
            && v.ends_with('}')                       //
            && v.substr(1, needle.length()) == needle;
    });
}

This uses

std::ranges::any_of to avoid writing the loop red-tape
std::string_view to get sub view comparison without copying
does early outs on size mismatch

UPDATE: To The Edit
In the general case, yes, make the ternary a reference expression:
bool bar(std::vector<std::string> const& vec, std::string const& s) {
    std::optional<std::string> tmp;
    if (!s.starts_with('{'))
        tmp = '{' + s + '}';

    std::string const& ref = tmp.has_value()? *tmp : s;
    return std::ranges::contains(vec, ref);
}

With Tests Live
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool foo(std::vector<std::string> const& haystack, std::string const& needle) {
    using std::ranges::any_of;

    if (needle.starts_with('{'))
        return any_of(haystack, [&](std::string const& v) { return v == needle; });

    return any_of(haystack, [&](std::string_view v) { //
        return v.length() == needle.length() + 2      //
            && v.starts_with('{')                     //
            && v.ends_with('}')                       //
            && v.substr(1, needle.length()) == needle;
    });
}

bool bar(std::vector<std::string> const& vec, std::string const& s) {
    std::optional<std::string> tmp;
    if (!s.starts_with('{'))
        tmp = '{' + s + '}';

    std::string const& ref = tmp.has_value()? *tmp : s;
    return std::ranges::contains(vec, ref);
}

void test(auto f) {
    std::vector<std::string> haystack = { "{a}", "{b}", "{c}" };

    assert(f(haystack, "{a}"));
    assert(f(haystack, "{b}"));
    assert(f(haystack, "{c}"));

    assert(f(haystack, "a"));
    assert(f(haystack, "b"));
    assert(f(haystack, "c"));

    assert(!f(haystack, "{d}"));
    assert(!f(haystack, "d"));
    assert(!f(haystack, "{a"));
    assert(!f(haystack, "b{"));
    assert(!f(haystack, "c}"));
    assert(!f(haystack, "{d"));
}

int main() {
    test(foo);
    test(bar);
}

Passes all tests

This works in this specific case, where one can avoid comparing curly braces. Please, take a look at the edit I made.

It's not good style to edit your question to invalidate existing answers. In general, my answer would still be to conditionally select zero-copy logic you require. Added test cases: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d1fdd57c6408da3

What are the empty comments for? Is that just to keep code formatters from merging lines?

@Barnar yup, that's exactly how that habit arose. I use it for formatting for SO answers, because they tend to be narrower than my editor

Added an update to address your edit. Now also avoiding value_or since it returns by value :)

I like the trick with using optional to manage the lifetime of the temporary. One can of course manually allocate the temporary. My question was basically about how to hide the management of the temporary.
